# How can I get specific value on SOAP response in Google Script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, soap, soap-client

I'm going to use only one set of SOAP response data from [this](https://orapiweb.pttor.com/oilservice/OilPrice.asmx) web service and add them to my Google Sheets for make a report, but the SOAP response give me so many unwanted data.

eg. This is when SOAP response and I only wanted the set of data that I've covered

https://www.img.in.th/images/8d764ce75879509f45e2398aa8f6baf2.png
[image]

How can I select only one set of my interested response?

Here's my Google App Script's code

```
function GetOilPriceProvincial(Language, DD, MM, YYYY, Province) { 

    var xml = '<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">'
    + '<soap12:Body>'
    + '<GetOilPriceProvincial xmlns=\"http://www.pttor.com\">'
    +   '<Language>' + Language + '</Language>'
    +     '<DD>' + DD + '</DD>'
    +     '<MM>' + MM + '</MM>'
    +     '<YYYY>' + YYYY + '</YYYY>'
    +     '<Province>' + Province + '</Province>'
    +   '</GetOilPriceProvincial>'
    + '</soap12:Body>'
    + '</soap12:Envelope>'
    //SOAP 1.2

    var options = {
      method: "post",
      contentType: "text/xml",
      charset: "utf-8",
      payload: xml,
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://orapiweb.pttor.com/oilservice/OilPrice.asmx?WSDL', options);

    Logger.log(response)
};


GetOilPriceProvincial('en', 1, 7, 2021, 'Nakhon Si Thammarat');
```

Thank you so much

Comment: What's the criteria? What identifies the desired content? Location? Price? Product? Date? All of them?

Comment: @Iamblichus I really want only PRICE. Identifiers for my interested PRICE are LOCATION = Thung Song; PRODUCT = Diesel PS. Maybe I describe with SQL will make it more clear (sorry for my bad english skill) I want PRICE from my interested LOCATION and PRODUCT like `select PRICE from SOAP_RESPONSE where LOCATION = 'Thung Song' and PRODUCT = 'Diesel'`

Comment: Can you provide more details on the hierarchical structure of the response? Where is the desired data located?